# Number theory ; divisibility

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$ and $k$ be positive integers. Prove that for every positive integer $d$ there exists a positive
integer $n$ such that $d$ divides $ka^n + n$.

P.S.-This problem is from an issue of AMM .I  would be glad to obtain its solution if someone were aware of this problem and its solution .

Comment: If anyone is in possession of its solution , can he or she please share it .

Comment: I would like elementary approaches . Anyone who knows the official solution to this problem.

Comment: This seems to be a generalization of one of IMO shortlisted problems in 2006.

Comment: which one ? ....... Ok I got which one .

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: Did you try to replace $2$ with $a$ in that proof (or another lettter, since there is already an $a$ in the proof)? Where did you have difficulties?

Comment: Someone with an answer ?